# How would one run a functions with same name?

Tags: elixir

I am new Elixir and really enjoying it. I hit a wall when trying to use functions with same name. Here is an example

```
defmodule ChangeName do
  def convert(:captilize, name), do:  String.capitalize(name)
  def convert(:lower, name), do: String.downcase(name)
end
```

I am using **iex** and the basic calls where ChangeName.convert.captilize but how do I run these functions?

Thanks

Comment: Also see this Q & A for more detail on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600513/elixir-function-overloading-with-different-arity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you give doesn't define two functions with the same name, but a single multiclause function. It is roughly equivalent to:

```
defmodule ChangeName do
  def convert(conversion, name) do
    case conversion do
      :capitalize -> String.capitalize(name)
      :lower -> String.downcase(name)
    end
  end
end
```

And is called accordingly:

```
ChangeName.convert(:capitalize, "john")
ChangeName.convert(:lower, "JOHN")
```

In fact in Erlang it's impossible to define two functions that have the same name and arity.