# What is the point of this ( reverse ) assignment / matching in this Elixir function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My only guess is that it is for verifying that it is a struct. otherwise what does `%User{}= user` do?

```
def change_user(%User{} = user) do
  User.changeset(user, %{})
end
```

It comes from the Phoenix framework and various generators etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you were wondering about the order, `%User{} = user` is the same as `user = %User{}` in patterns.

Comment: This **not an assignment** by any means. This is [pattern matching](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html). I would recommend starting with reading language guides instead of diving into frameworks.

Comment: This allows function overloading through pattern matching - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600513/elixir-function-overloading-with-different-arity

Answer (score 1):

Yup, that will just verify that the input can be matched to/is a `%User{}` struct and nothing else.

The point of it is to identify bugs (by static program analysis) or force runtime errors/crashes so your program won't do anything harmful (hopefully).

Comment: The main point is to provide an ability to define multiple clauses for the function based on pattern matching arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you think of it more as type-hint.  Although it *is* a pattern match, the syntax here reminds me of other languages (e.g. PHP, Python, or Go) that put data types in the function signatures.

But since it's Elixir, it IS a pattern match, and it is an idiomatic way to communicate the intent of that particular function clause or to set yourself up to define other function clauses.  For example, imagine these function clauses defined alongside the example you provided:

```
def change_user(%LegacyUser{} = legacy_user) do
  LegacyUser.changeset(legacy_user, %{})
end

def change_user(arg) do
  Logger.error("Unsupported argument given to change_user/1: #{inspect(arg)}")
end
```

Although functionally, it doesn't matter if you do `%User{} = user` or `user = %User{}`, it is more idiomatic to use the former.